# What's the size of a HMACSHA2 hash in Crypt::PBKDF2 in Perl?

Tags: perl, crypt, pbkdf2

I want to store password hashes in a database. Hashes will be generated with

```perl
my $PBKDF2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(
    hash_class => 'HMACSHA2',
    hash_args => {
        sha_size => 512,
    },
    iterations => 10000,
    salt_len => 10,
);
```

In the Pod of Crypt::PBKDF2 I find:

> The default size (in bytes, not bits) of the output hash. If a value
> isn't provided, the output size depends on the hash_class / hasher
> selected, and will equal the output size of the backend hash (e.g. 20
> bytes for HMACSHA1).

But what actually IS the default output size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32 bytes

You can find this information in the [source code](https://metacpan.org/release/Crypt-PBKDF2/source/lib/Crypt/PBKDF2/Hash/HMACSHA2.pm) of [`Crypt::PBKDF2::Hash::HMACSHA2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PBKDF2::Hash::HMACSHA2). The code defining the default size is:

```
has 'sha_size' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => Type::Tiny->new(
    name => 'SHASize',
    parent => Enum[qw( 224 256 384 512 )],
    display_name => 'valid number of bits for SHA-2',
  ),
  default => 256,
);
```

The function used to return the size divides `sha_size` by 8:

```
sub hash_len {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->sha_size() / 8;
}
```

Thus returning 256/8 = 32 by default.

Comment: So as I use 512, it's 64 for me. What I really was after was the size I need in the database. Seems by adding some base64 overhead plus the standard stuff the module adds, I end up with 135byte required for storing. I was a bit unsure whether or not the amount of bytes might change. Thanks to you pointing me to the source I'm pretty confident, the size will always be the same.